# How do I use buttons to select different elements from my document?

Tags: jquery, select, button, show-hide, jquery-clone

I created a web page of my resume, which is organized by skills.

At the top of the page, I have three buttons in the navigation:

```
<p>Choose the type of experience you are interested in seeing:</p>
<button class="button-w" type="button">Writing/Editing Experience</button>
<button class="button-t" type="button">Teaching/Training Experience</button>
<button class="button-c" type="button">Current Experience</button>
```

I gave each corresponding section in the html document its own class. For example:  to contain all my writing/editing experience.

Then I wrote jquery to remove/detach all the other sections but the writing/editing. See below. It works for the first button I click on. But the problem is, when I then click on the "teaching/training experience" button, because I have already removed that content when I clicked on the "writing/editing experience" button, I get nothing.

Here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".button-w").click(function(){
    $("section, div").detach(".teaching, .current");

});

$(".button-t").click(function(){
   $("section, div").detach(".writing, .current");
});

$(".button-c").click(function(){
    $("section, div").detach(".writing, .teaching");
});
});
```

I think what I need is either:
--to use "show"/"hide" and add some kind of conditional statement so that if one is showing the others stuff is hiding for each button selection
OR
--to order the jquery so that when I click on each new button, it first restores my original content and then removes all but the selected sections.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

[`.detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) Remove the set of matched elements from the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

I feel like that's not what you really want to do. Just [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) some elements would be enought.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".button-w").click(function(){
    $(".teaching, .current").hide();
    $(".writing").show();
  });

  $(".button-t").click(function(){
   $(".writing, .current").hide();
   $(".teaching").show();
  });

  $(".button-c").click(function(){
    $(".writing, .teaching").hide();
    $(".current").show();
  });
});
```

```css
section div{
  display:none;
  margin-top:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Choose the type of experience you are interested in seeing:</p>
<button class="button-w" type="button">Writing/Editing Experience</button>
<button class="button-t" type="button">Teaching/Training Experience</button>
<button class="button-c" type="button">Current Experience</button>

<section>
  <div class="writing">Writing/Editing Experience</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="teaching">Teaching/Training Experience</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="current">Current Experience</div>
</section>
```

Now with the above, you have to write a handler for each button... And each time you wish to add a section, you have to "duplicate" the handler.

You can shorten that by using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to each button.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".btn-section").click(function(){
    $("section div").hide();
    var section = $(this).data("section");
    $("."+section).show();
  });
  
});
```

```css
section div{
  display:none;
  margin-top:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Choose the type of experience you are interested in seeing:</p>
<button class="btn-section" type="button" data-section="writing">Writing/Editing Experience</button>
<button class="btn-section" type="button" data-section="teaching">Teaching/Training Experience</button>
<button class="btn-section" type="button" data-section="current">Current Experience</button>

<section>
  <div class="writing">Writing/Editing Experience</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="teaching">Teaching/Training Experience</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="current">Current Experience</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here, because I realized really what I wanted to solve my need was to create a filter. So I created handles by labeling each HTML element I wanted to filter out:

```
<section class="filter writing">
<section class="filter teaching">
<section class="filter current">
```

I made the navigation menu:

```
<nav>
<div class="container">
<h5>What experience would  you like to see?</h5>
    <ul>
        <li class="button active" data-filter="all">All</li>
        <li class="button" data-filter="writing">Writing/Editing Experience</li>
        <li class="button" data-filter="teaching">Teaching/Training Experience</li>
        <li class="button" data-filter="current">Current Experience</li>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

And then I applied the jquery below (which I learned from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPyT6zyPz7g) to the HTML handles and using menu buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".button").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr("data-filter");
    if (value == "all")
    {
        $(".filter").show("1000");
    }
    else
    {
        $(".filter").not("."+value).hide("1000");
        $(".filter").filter("."+value).show("1000");
    }
    //add active class
    $("ul .button").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    })
})
})
```

Leaving out the CSS here, which added the hovering to the menu, etc., this accomplished what I wanted.